# Which one is the correct sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning, word-difference, inversion

my teacher asked to me today. but i still confused

which one is the correct sentence

> Jane prefers homemade food and so does Henry.

or

> Jane prefers homemade food and so Henry does.

which sentence is correct?

Comment: Only the first is idiomatic. In principle, one could say *...and Henry does so too*, but that's a dated/formal/poetic construction, probably best avoided today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence is completely correct.

As FumbleFingers pointed out in the comment, the second one could become correct on principle: "Jane prefers homemade food and Henry does so too." That's a bit archaic, but it would be understood. Better would be: "Jane prefers homemade food and Henry does too."

The meanings are all the same; it's basically just a style question.